# How to return file path without url link?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have

```
http://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg
```

How do I return

```
uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use the [URI parsing](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI.html) that is part of the Ruby standard library
than to experiment with some regular expression that may or may not take every
possible special case into account.

```
require 'uri'

url = "http://foo.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg"

path = URI.parse(url).path  
# => "/uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg"

path[1..-1]
# => "uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg"
```

No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

```
"http://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg".sub("http://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/","")
```

would be an explicit version, in which you `sub`stitute the homepage-part with an empty string.

For a more universal approach I would recommend a regular expression, similar to this one:

```
string = "http://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg"
string.sub(/(http:\/\/)*.*?\.\w{2,3}\//,"")
```

If it's needed, I could explain the regular expression.

Comment: btw. the sub on the string variable only returns the "uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg"-String, if you really want to change it, you would have to use .sub!

Answer (score 0):

The cheap answer is to just strip everything before the first single `/`.

Better answers are "[How do I process a URL in ruby to extract the component parts (scheme, username, password, host, etc)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274213/how-do-i-process-a-url-in-ruby-to-extract-the-component-parts-scheme-username)" and "[Remove subdomain from string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983158/remove-subdomain-from-string-in-ruby)".

Answer (score 0):

```
link = "http://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg"
path = link.match /\/\/[^\/]*\/(.*)/
path[1]
#=> "uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg"
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone recommended this approach as well:

```
URI.parse(URI.escape('http://foobar.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/users/15/photos/12/foo.jpg')).path[1..-1]
```

Are there any disadvantages using something like this versus a regexp approach?

Comment: This should be added into the question using the [edit] button as it is not a complete answer....